# MySQL Query to select last record for each of the past 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select

I'm trying to come up with a MySQL query to select the last record from each of the previous 7 days. If 1 of the previous 7 days is missing data, I would only get back 6 records. Here's what I have:

```
SELECT tracking.* FROM tracking
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT MAX(lastChecked) AS maxLastChecked, id FROM tracking 
    WHERE lastChecked >= DATE_SUB(lastChecked, INTERVAL 7 DAY ) 
        GROUP BY DAY(lastChecked)) as Lookup ON Lookup.id = tracking.id
            WHERE tracking.propertyID = 1 ORDER BY tracking.lastChecked ASC LIMIT 7
```

Basically what this should do is select the final recorded entry for propertyID = 1 in the tracking table for each of the past 7 days (starting on today). However, this query is returning this to me (more than ONLY records within the last 7 days):

```
ID    propertyID  lastChecked              value
2     1           2012-01-25 05:30:00      280
1     1           2012-01-26 12:34:02      268
5     1           2012-01-27 09:51:31      268
83    1           2012-02-13 00:01:07      276
```

Any help to fix this up would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Confirmation... is the "ID" column auto-increment primary key, and 2... is the LastChecked always corresponding to when it was added and not modifiable by someone making ID 83 and earlier time than ID 84 or similar?  Also, do you have an index on the lastchecked column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT tracking.* FROM tracking
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT MAX(lastChecked) AS maxLastChecked, id FROM tracking 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(lastChecked,NOW())<=7
        GROUP BY DAY(lastChecked)) as Lookup ON Lookup.id = tracking.id
            WHERE tracking.propertyID = 1 ORDER BY tracking.lastChecked ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have a system date instead of "lastChecked" in this part:

```
DATE_SUB(lastChecked, INTERVAL 7 DAY )
```

Should be:

```
DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE lastChecked >= DATE_SUB(lastChecked, INTERVAL 7 DAY )
```

This condition of your code is going to be true for every record as lastChecked is always greater than lastChecked -7. 
So, if you need data of last 7 days replace it with

```
WHERE lastChecked >= DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )
```